# Настройка ImageMinimizerPlugin в Webpack 5

Tags: frontend, webpack

Я использую **ImageMinimizerPlugin** , но он не сжимает изображения, что в настройке не так?

```
new ImageMinimizerPlugin({                                
            minimizerOptions: {
                plugins: [
                    ["gifsicle", { interlaced: true }],
                    ["jpegtran", { progressive: true }],
                    ["optipng", { optimizationLevel: 7 }],
                ]
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

plugins: [
"imagemin-gifsicle",
["imagemin-mozjpeg",{
progressive: true,
quality: 80
}],
["imagemin-pngquant",{
quality: [0.5, 0.7]
}],
"imagemin-svgo",
],

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]